# Terraform: set desired capacity for Beanstalk's autoscaling group

Tags: terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

AWS allows to set MinSize and MaxSize, but not DesiredCapacity.

The desired capacity stays where it was when you change min/max size without defaulting to minimum.

I looked for settings to set DesiredCapacity but couldn't find it for beanstalk.

Example: Before setting these values, min/max/desired was 1/4/4.
Changing min/max to 1/2, desired went down to 2
If I change min/max to 1/1, desired went to 1.  Then I change max back to 2, and desired stayed at 1.

I can do that, but it seems hacky, and I'd rather just properly set the values I want.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "this" {
  name="my_beanstalk_env"
  ...
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MinSize"
    value     = 1
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:asg"
    name      = "MaxSize"
    value     = 2
  }

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Resource: [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalingasg)

Comment: There is `DesiredCapacity` settings, just for different domain. Try setting it and see if it works.